# Request blocked (Cross-Origin Request) The same-origin policy doesn't allow

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-sanctum

I have a vuejs3 spa that uses a laravel 10 api.
Everything works well locally i.e. in my computer
I tried to use my app on a shared hosting like this

Laravel api on compta-be.domain.fr
Front end Vue on compta.domain.fr

Here is my global axios instance

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV ==='development'){
    axios.defaults.baseURL="http://localhost:8000";
}
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    axios.defaults.baseURL="http://compta-be.localhost:8000";
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Referer']="https://compta.localhost";
}

axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept']="application/json";
```

here is the relevant part of the laravel .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:HMCK36s76cGQ18aHGTyU/zV2k4rMnbby527cy0UcTuI=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://compta-be.localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=https://compta.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='https://compta.localhost'
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

config/sanctum.php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Stateful Domains
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
| authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
| and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
|
*/

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
'%s%s%s',
'compta.localhost,compta.localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
```

))),

config/cors.php

```
        /*
        <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

I get a cors error

Blocage d’une requête multiorigine (Cross-Origin Request) : la politique « Same Origin » ne permet pas de consulter la ressource distante située sur http://compta-be.localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie. Raison : l’en-tête CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » ne correspond pas à « http://localhost:3000 »

in english
Request blocked (Cross-ORigin Request) The same orign politic doesn't allow to consult a remot resource located at http://compta-be.localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie. Reason the CORS header « Access-control-allow-origin » doesn't match « http://localhost:3000 »

I cannot locate my error. I need help

Post Addition
vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: You list `compta.localhost:3000` as an allowed origin in your CORS configuration. This isn't a valid Web-origin value. Try `http://compta.localhost:3000` instead. Also, your question contains conflicting information; please clarify from where you're sending the request: `http://compta.localhost:3000` or `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what you suggest but it failed also withCross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://compta-be.localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)

Comment: I have installed laravel api (the backend) on compta-be.mydomain.fr and the built vuejs frontend on compta.mydomain.fr.  I don't know if I should keep the 3000 port in the adresses. I added the vite config to my inital post.

Comment: I made a lot of changes in my config and reported them in my initial post. In particular, I added a Referer header when in production as Laravel Sanctum doc requires. Now I can see the header "Origin: https://compta.denentzat.fr" in the request to "http://compta-be.localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie" but  I still get the message in the console saying Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://compta-be.localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Comment: I will not try anything new until I read your answer.

Comment: It seems that using the true domain everywhere name instead of localhost solved the trouble. More over the backend is served on normal port 80 and not 8000 in production.